# Add WYSIWYG to order comments - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, wysiwyg

I want add a WYSIWYG editor in the order comments on the order view page.

[image]

When I go to Sales->Orders and I access an order I can add a comment but not only in plain text.

Does anyone know how to change this to a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: refer : https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-wysiwyg-editor-to-admin-form/

Answer (score 0):

Try change elements to  **elements: "comentario"** your element id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
   tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "comentario",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "inlinepopups,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
    extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
    theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
    apply_source_formatting : 'true',
    convert_urls : 'false',
    force_br_newlines : 'true',
    doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: If it is work. please accept the answer it will help others

Comment: I add this code in a script but not work

Comment: i will check and come back.

Comment: The problem is in console tinyMCE is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working version

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function()
        {
           tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements: "history_comment",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "inlinepopups,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
            extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
            theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
            apply_source_formatting : 'true',
            convert_urls : 'false',
            force_br_newlines : 'true',
            doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

          });
        };
        </script>
```